# Генирация объектов которые не пересекаються в пространстве

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Есть такой скрипт генерации кружков, как можно реализовать его что бы они не пересикались?

[jsfiddle.net/f2tyn](http://jsfiddle.net/f2tyn/)

Comment: это реализация а не алгоритм :) считайте центры и радиусы, заносите в массив, при генерации нового считайте расстояние до всех остальных, если не подходит (любое из расстояний меньше радиуса), генерируйте заново.

Comment: Простите, простите, простите меня

генерация

пересекаются

пересекались

Comment: [Правописание -тся и -ться в глаголах](http://tsya.ru/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/Rr9zL/1/).

Исправления и описание кода:

- Как Я понимаю из описания задания, необходима генерация именно кружков. Может это Я упорот, а может с браузером проблемы или со скриптом, но на Вашем [примере](http://jsfiddle.net/f2tyn/) Я видел квадраты. Исправил на круги.
- boxShadow теперь не используется из-за проблематичности с вычислением пересечений кругов. Вместо него задействованы атрибуты width & height.
- Код переписан в процедурно-ориентированном стиле. Мне в JS так проще работать с небольшими скриптами.
- Функция "add_point" пытается создать круг, что не пересекается другими. Причем пытается она это сделать ровно такое количество раз, сколько указано в локальной переменной "limit". Если есть возможность и желание пожертвовать скоростью выполнения скрипта в пользу его надежности, то попробуйте увеличить значение переменной "limit".

Сам процесс поиска наличия перекрытий между окружностями выглядит так:

```
// x1, y1, r1 - left, top и радиус для первой окружности
// x2, y2, r2 - left, top и радиус для второй окружности
// true, если пересекаются
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2 ,2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2)) < (r1 + r2)
```

А вообще, рекомендую использовать [d3js](http://d3js.org/) при [выполнении подобных задач](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1748247).

Comment: Спасибо, что надо, сейчас буду разбираться